# Is there an IDE for jquery similar to Visual Studio in that I can see where the definition of a function is via hotkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there an IDE for jquery similar to Visual Studio in that I can see where the definition of a function is via hotkey?

I'm wondering if there is an easier way of doing this type of development that goes beyond using Notepad++. It would be wonderful if I could see where the class is defined by right clicking the instance and doing a goto definition, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with using Visual Studio?  If you want something like visual studio, why not use visual studio?

Comment: I don't have enough money to buy it.

Comment: Note that jQuery is not a language, so what you're really looking for is an IDE for javascript.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) supports auto-completion for a variety of JavaScript libraries, including jQuery. It is available for [Visual Studio 2012 as a plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790). Alternatively you could try [JetBrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), which can do some auto completion with or without TypeScript.

Note that JavaScript is a dynamic language and for instance you often cannot deduce precise data typing before runtime. Thus, even good IDEs cannot provide you with full autocompletion. A particularly good Q&A discussion on the topic can be found here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131561/ides-for-dynamic-languages-how-far-can-you-get

Comment: Visual studio express for web has a typescript plugin as well and is free, you have to register it though but no costs involved.

Answer (score 2):

This is really not a great question is it's more about personal preference but give Brackets a try http://brackets.io/

Another alternative is Jetbrains WebStorm http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: I think it goes beyond personal preference. Else, we'd still be developing C++ applications in Notepad++ which would be like programming in the stone age. With more advanced development, it requires more advanced tools. Also anyone serious about writing up a website with 10,000 lines plus would want a more efficient way to find functions that they declared.

Comment: True, I should've been more specific. This is not a great question for stackoverflow. programmers.stackexchange.com is probably a better fit. These questions usually end up as more of a debate.